# Binding Native library (*.so) and Java library in Xamarin Android C#

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to make use of a third party library in a Xamarin Android application. The third party library is mainly written in C++ in a *.so file, and a few *.java files and possibly file in folders res and asset. The *.java file performs validation works and exposes C++ function via JNI.

How can I go about wrapping both libraries (*.so file, *.java files and possibly files in folders res and assert) so that it can be used by Xamarin Android C#?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-library-project

Comment: You could refer to: [Xamarin Android Using Native Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/native-libraries)

Comment: I know that, but the problem as mentioned on opening post is that the .so is called by *.java files, both of which are parts of the third party library. Any idea?

Comment: @Pingpong Did you ever solve this?